# Is there a way to switch distributions without losing any data (settings, applications, home folder)?

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, upgrade, xubuntu, lubuntu

Yes, I know. This might be a duplicate. However, this time it's a bit different.

I'm considering of switching from Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to Xubuntu (exact same version). I could try the "Something else" option at the "Installation type" screen and not lose any data in the `/home` folder, however, this deletes the `/var`, `/etc`, `/lib` folders and others, as the popup that appears after the confirmation says.

*(could not find any image, sorry for that. If an editor can add this, proceed.)*

So, I was wondering, can I do a distribution switch without losing these folders? Or should I do an upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 (like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) site says) and become a "daredevil" until 20.04 LTS is released? (I mean hopping releases frequently.) Because, although I have created a script which does the job for me (package reinstallation and system updates), I do not want to wait several hours for the PPA addition, package download and system update processes to complete.

(I do not really care about settings, nor the default theme/icons. The Xubuntu installation must change these or there will be a conflict. The thing I care the most (besides data in the /home folder) is the **packages** that I have downloaded over several months.)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You don't really need to change the distro. In my opinion these distros just differ in their default desktop environment. You can install that of latter and remove the earlier one. Also, it is recommended to stick to LTS version unless required on move to non-LTS. So, wait until 20.04

Comment: @Kulfy I also considered that, however I think that when you install a secondary desktop evironment, you bloat the system by installing the desktop's necessary packages (e.g. Thunar) when you already have equivalents (PCManFM). Thus, more space is compromised and you expect to lose some storage. Also, Xubuntu's icons, wallpapers, themes etc. are going to be installed on top of Lubuntu's. Also a storage waste. That's why I support re-installations. BUT, disregarding what I said above, what you said is correct. I might do that instead.

Comment: While you may be impatient, and while you may not like 'bloat' (who does?), do recall that sometimes there is simply no easy answer. If your data is valuable to you, back it up regardless of whichever method of flavor-switching you choose to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm considering of switching from Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS to Xubuntu (exact same version).

The only difference between Lubuntu and Xubuntu is the default desktop environment. To install the Xubuntu desktop environment, simply run

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

This will install the Xubuntu desktop. Log out, and select XFCE on the login screen.

To remove Lubuntu's desktop, run

```
sudo apt remove lubuntu-desktop && sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for! I thought that if you uninstall the default desktop (lubuntu-desktop in this case) it would damage the system files, but nope! I was wrong! Thanks for helping me out!